# After STM instruction, why does R6 register hold memory location of 10, 11, 12?

Tags: assembly, arm

In Wiley's Practical Reverse Engineering book, page 59, the following example is used to explain the LDM/STM instructions.

Shouldn't line 30 show R6 with the values of r3, r4, r5?
Doesn't line 10 store the values in R6 at the memory locations of the destination?

```
02: Breakpoint 1 at 0x8344
03: (gdb) disas main
04: Dump of assembler code for function main:
05:    0x00008344 <+0>:     ldr     r6, =mem  ; edited a bit
06:    0x00008348 <+4>:     mov     r0, #10
07:    0x0000834c <+8>:     mov     r1, #11
08:    0x00008350 <+12>:    mov     r2, #12
09:    0x00008354 <+16>:    ldm     r6, {r3, r4, r5}  ; IA mode
10:    0x00008358 <+20>:    stm     r6, {r0, r1, r2}  ; IA mode
11: …
12: (gdb) r
13: Breakpoint 1, 0x00008344 in main ()
14: (gdb) si
15: 0x00008348 in main ()
16: (gdb) x/3x $r6
17: 0x1050c <mem>:  0x00000001      0x00000002      0x00000003
18: (gdb) si
19: 0x0000834c in main ()
20: …
21: (gdb)
22: 0x00008358 in main ()
23: (gdb) info reg r3 r4 r5
24: r3             0x1      1
25: r4             0x2      2
26: r5             0x3      3
27: (gdb) si
28: 0x0000835c in main ()
29: (gdb) x/3x $r6
30: 0x1050c <mem>:  0x0000000a      0x0000000b      0x0000000c
```

Comment: ldm and stm mean load and store multiple.  IA means increment after, in this case there is no exclamation point.  ldmia r6!,{r3,r4,r5}  would start storing r3 at the address in r6 then after it would add 12 to r6.  without the ! then r6 remains unchanged.  This is reading 12 bytes from the address in r6 then storing 12 other bytes to that address. and r6 is not changed in the code shown.

Comment: The disassembly would help (with machine code).  This is all documented in the ARM documentation.  What part of the documentation do you not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your `ldm` instruction took what was at the memory location pointed to by `r6` and loaded that into `r3/4/5` (a memory to register operation), should be a dead giveaway that `stm` will do the opposite (a register to memory operation).

In other words, it will store `r0/1/2` (which you'e set to `10/11/12` decimal or `a/b/c` hexadecimal) into the memory pointed to by `r6`, exactly what you're seeing:

```
30: 0x1050c <mem>:  0x0000000a      0x0000000b      0x0000000c
```

This matches the other load/store instructions on ARM and, indeed, quite a lot of other CPUs, you:

- load *from* memory; and
- store *to* memory.